# Jackson JSON how to set http connection and read timeout

Tags: java, json, jackson, tomcat7, jersey-2.0

(jersey-common=2.21.0, jackson-core=2.6.1)

How do I set http connection timeouts (connect, read) if createParser(URL url) was invoked? What is the default values used?

```
    JsonFactory jsonF = new JsonFactory();
    jsonF.enable(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE);
    JsonParser jsonP = jsonF.createParser(url); // URL instance
    try {
        JsonToken token;
        while ( (token=jsonP.nextToken()) != null) {
           if (token == JsonToken.START_OBJECT)
           ..rest "json sax" parser code...
        }
    } finally {
        jsonP.close();
    }
```

I have few times a week recurring problem when webapp stops reading json sources, task is autorun every 30 minutes. I suspect this http call stalls and starts piling up until JVM goes down.

Should I not use *createParser(URL)* function in production apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could hack the values

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "10000");
System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout", "10000");
```

More on the settings can be found on 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

Or you can instead do a proper call and then pass the result into the json parser. I would go with the latter.

So to put it simply while URL is great light weight alternative I suggest switching to apache http client or some high level solution.

Comment: I accept this answer, most likely that method was too light-weight usecase. I go for passing InputStream taken from HttpURLConnection, I don't want to mess with system level default values especially in Tomcat webapp environment. I skip ApacheHttp for not introducing new dependencies, this is such a simple use-case.

Answer (score 3):

That particular read method is for convenience, but not configurable and generally not that useful for most production usage.

Instead, you may want to obtain `InputStream` from `URL` endpoints using other means, then pass it to `ObjectMapper` / `ObjectReader`; this allows for full control over details of connection, timeouts and so forth. It allows lets you use other HTTP clients than the default one JDK comes equipped with.

Comment: Do you have some good examples of ObjectMapper+ObjectReader used ín adhoc utility functions? I have always used JsonFactory+JsonParser to read large json documents using jsonP.nextToken() loop, it suits well and wish to keep this "sax streaming" use case.

Comment: You can also pass `InputStream` to `JsonFactory`, same difference. No need to change from streaming to databinding if you do not want to.